# My CSS looks perfect on desktop, but leaves a 2-5 pixel line to the right on mobile, how do I find the issue?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been poking at this for hours now.

I used the wordpress twentythirteen theme as a starting point for a landing page I am working on. I have it looking exactly how I want it on desktop, but when I switch to my iphone, the footer doesn't render properly and there is a line that runs vertically along the right side of the frame.

Website: detroitvehiclewraps.tectonicsindustries.com

I have gone through everything I can think of and cannot make the problem go away.  I deleted the PHP that detects mobile, as for the time being I want the site to display identically on mobile and desktop.  Any help any of the CSS wizards on here could provide would be appreciated.  I know I am just missing some inane little thing and I am absolutely losing my damn mind.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it iPhone only or at a specific width? At the moment there doesn't appear to be any responsiveness built in when re-sizing my browser.

Comment: You could try changing your user agent on desktop to help you find the issue: http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/16/change-user-agent-chrome-safari-firefox/

Comment: @KristofFeys I tried changing the user agent, but the issue doesn't appear. Only when it is actually on the phone.

Comment: @Paulie_D it appears to be all mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert a `viewport` meta tag into the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=990px, user-scalable=yes">
```

Iphone's default viewport is 980px wide, your content is 990px wide so the device scales it down. This is the "line" (10px) you observed on the right (the background color of `body` is white).

Note: you are mixing fluid and fixed with layout, try to clean it up a little bit. You should check out media queries too.